# package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist error

Tags: java, maven, java-8, java-11

I am trying to run "**mvn clean install**" command, but I get the following error:

> java:[42,22] package javax.xml.bind does not exist

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: The question doesn't match the description. "javax.xml.bind" and "javax.xml.bind.annotation" are different packages, and the answers are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

into your pom.xml file

Comment: and after adding should I directly retry running the mvn clean install command?

Comment: Sure. Possibly you will have to add more dependencies and some more setting. You did not present your pom.xml and other essential settings

Comment: and I had to do this as well otherwise my test was failing `mvn clean install -DskipTests`...
I'm not a java developer so I don't know if skipping these tests were a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

The library `javax.xml.bind` has been removed from Java 11 release.
[Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8190378) 
For fixing this you have add those dependencies explicitly in your POM file or add it to your classpath accordingly.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding it to your POM you can build the maven project. First time you can skip tests.

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Answer (score 0):

Download jaxb API jar file, and add it as an external jar to the Java build path.

Comment: That's the reason why Maven exist to prevent such things.